# Build against rabbitmq-c

Tags: c, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect to rabbitmq in c and it is failing every single time. Here is how I did it.

Downloaded rabbitmq-c

Installed it (`make && make install`) just to make sure dependencies are satisfied.

Modified connection variables in `amqp_sendstring.c`

Rebuilt using `make`, ran `./amqp_sendstring` and it worked

Then I started creating my own files and compiling them through gcc using:

```
gcc -lrabbitmq -o j_test test.c
```

Ironically it fails to link against librabbitmq with the errors below:

```
/tmp/cc63IlXq.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `amqp_new_connection'
test.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `amqp_destroy_connection'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I removed everything starting with ampq_*. Voila! It was successfully built. That's to me an indicator that gcc is able to find the headers but not the lib.

Here is test.c source code:

```
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_framing.h>
int main(int argc, char const * const *argv) {
   amqp_connection_state_t conn;
   conn = amqp_new_connection();
   amqp_destroy_connection(conn);
   return 0;
}
```

Would someone please point me to the right direction?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am on an ubuntu box (12.04). Think it is implicitly implied in the statements above though.

Answer (score 8):

When you compile your program you have to tell to `gcc` not only the name of the library you are going to use (`-lrabbimtq`), but also the path (i.e. the directory) where the library should be searched from (`-L/path/to/rabbitmq-c`) during linking. `gcc` (or the linker) will always look for some default directories, but your [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/) library is not available in those directories.

So your `gcc` command-line should look like:

```
gcc -I/path/to/rabbitmq-c-header-dir -L/path/to/rabbitmq-c-lib-dir -o j_test test.c -lrabbitmq
```

Note that you have to tell the location of header files (`-I`) and that [the position of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487723/) `-lrabbitmq` is important.

In the example below directory `~/src/rabbitmq-c` is the location of my clone of  rabbitmq-c.

Locations of the headers and the shared library:

```
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ find . -name amqp.h
./librabbitmq/amqp.h
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ find . -name librabbitmq.so
./librabbitmq/.libs/librabbitmq.so
~/src/rabbitmq-c$
```

Compiling and linking your example program:

```
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ cat > stacko.c
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_framing.h>
int main(int argc, char const * const *argv) {
   amqp_connection_state_t conn;
   conn = amqp_new_connection();
   amqp_destroy_connection(conn);
   return 0;
}
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ gcc -Ilibrabbitmq -g -Wall -c stacko.c
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ gcc -Llibrabbitmq/.libs -g -Wall -o stacko stacko.o -lrabbitmq
~/src/rabbitmq-c$
```

With shared libraries one have to tell also during runtime where the libraries will be found:

```
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ ./stacko 
./stacko: error while loading shared libraries: librabbitmq.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=librabbitmq/.libs ./stacko 
~/src/rabbitmq-c$
```

You can check what libraries an executable uses with `ldd`:

```
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ ldd ./stacko 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00d7d000)
    librabbitmq.so.0 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00396000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002d6000)
~/src/rabbitmq-c$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=librabbitmq/.libs ldd ./stacko 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x001c8000)
    librabbitmq.so.0 => librabbitmq/.libs/librabbitmq.so.0 (0x00f77000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x001c9000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00cc3000)
~/src/rabbitmq-c$
```

See also [g++: how to specify preference of library path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727033/).