# Attempting to build against rabbitmq-c

Tags: c, rabbitmq

I have written my own .c and am trying to link it to the necessary files in rabbitmq-c, but am unable to do so.

I have rabbitmq-c and its examples running properly.

I am using a centos 7 machine.

I have tried the advice of the answer on the post [Build against rabbitmq-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028112/build-against-rabbitmq-c)

However,
When issuing the last step from that page

`gcc -Llibrabbitmq/.libs -g -Wall -o test test.o -lrabbitmq`

I get the error 
"collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" and then a list of undefined references. The undefined references all begin with "die" if it has to do with me missing something specific.

Help would be greatly appreciated