# g++ compile error: undefined reference to a shared library function which exists

Tags: g++, shared-libraries, ld, hdf5, undefined-reference

I recently installed the **hdf5** library on an ubuntu machine, and am now having trouble linking to the exported functions. I wrote a simple test script **readHDF.cpp** to explain the issue:

```
#include <hdf5.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  hid_t     h5_file_id = H5Fopen(argv[1], H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
  return 0;
}
```

The compile command is

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/hdf5/lib -I$HOME/hdf5/include \
    -L$HOME/hdf5/lib -l:$HOME/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so readHDF.cpp
```

which returns the following error

```
/tmp/cc6DXdxV.o: In function `main':  
readHDF.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `H5check_version'  
readHDF.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `H5Fopen'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am confused because the **nm** command seems to say that the function has been exported:

```
nm -C $HOME/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so | grep H5check_version
```

which returns

```
0000000000034349 T H5check_version
```

and a similar result for `H5Fopen`. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong? Not sure if it helps, but if I comment out the `H5Fopen` portion of the script, then it compiles fine:

```
#include <hdf5.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
hid_t     h5_file_id;// = H5Fopen(argv[1], H5F_ACC_RDWR, H5P_DEFAULT);
return 0;
}
```

Also there are multiple versions of hdf5 installed on the server which are used by various python modules such as h5py and tables, but I couldn't get any of them to work, so I installed this version in my local directory and changed the rpath options for g++ linker.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, solved. The issue was in the placement of the -lhdf5 in the compile command. Apparently -lhdf5 should be placed after readHDF.cpp. For instance `g++ -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/hdf5/lib -L$HOME/hdf5/lib -I$HOME/hdf5/include  readHDF.cpp -lhdf5` will compile with no problems, but `g++ -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/hdf5/lib -L$HOME/hdf5/lib -I$HOME/hdf5/include -lhdf5 readHDF.cpp` will fail with the undefined reference errors. Interestingly, this was only a problem for Ubuntu 12.04, as both compile commands worked for Ubuntu 10.04.

Found the answer with explanation at this post:

[undefined reference to symbol even when nm indicates that this symbol is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456581/undefined-reference-to-symbol-even-when-nm-indicates-that-this-symbol-is-present)

I guess placing -lXXX after the script is safer practice.

Comment: Strange. Putting `-lhdf5` before the script, and everything works fine. When I put it after the script, it gives libraries errors.

Comment: +500 if i could

Comment: Can confirm that this also fixed the same problem on Windows with Cygwin

Answer (score 6):

This is not a bug. See
[C++ shared library undefined reference to `FooClass::SayHello()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748837/c-shared-library-undefined-reference-to-fooclasssayhello)

"Recent versions of GCC reuqire that you put the object files and libraries in the order that they depend on each other ..."

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `-lhdf5` in the compile command. Also, there's no need for `-l:$HOME/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so`

This should work: `$ g++ -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/hdf5/lib -I$HOME/hdf5/include -L$HOME/hdf5/lib -lhdf5 readHDF5.cpp`

Comment: I tried that originally and it gave the same error. There are multiple versions of libhdf5.so* in $HOME/hdf5/lib for instance libhdf5.so.6 and libhdf5.so.6.0.3 etc so I though that being more specific would help, but it didn't.

Comment: And what about the -lhdf5? I can reproduce the exact linker error you have in your question on my machine, and adding -lhdf5 solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, adding the -lhdf5 didn't help. It is a very strange bug. I installed in exactly the same way on an Ubuntu 10 machine and it worked ok.