# multi file access to singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton, global-variables

I have a singleton class.

In A.h

```
class single
{
    public:
        static single *Instance;
        static single* getInstance()
        { if(!Instance) Instance = new single; 
          return Instance;
        }
        void hello () { cout<<"Hello"; }
    private: single(){ }
}
```

In A.cpp

```
single *single::Instance = 0;
std::auto_ptr <single> SINGLE_OBJ (single::getInstance());
```

In B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

SINGLE_OBJ->hello();
```

I get the following error:
SINGLE_OBJ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Why is the memory of the instance managed externally through `auto_ptr`? The fact that it is allocated using `new` is an implementation detail. It should be kept internal to `single` for encapsulation, and to ensure that memory is cleaned up even if the user doesn't put the pointer in an `auto_ptr`. By the way, C++11 replaces the deprecated `std::auto_ptr` class template with `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `SINGLE_OBJ` visible in `B.cpp` you should declare it in `A.h.` i.e. :

```
extern std::auto_ptr <single> SINGLE_OBJ;
```

also, why are you using `std::auto_ptr`, its deprecated - you should switch to `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: That worked fine when I compiled the code and created a ".o" and a ".so" successfully. But when another application tries to use this ".o" or ".so", I get an error that says Undefined reference to SINGLE_OBJ

Comment: @user2524261 you might want to start a new question, you didnt mention you want to use it in shared library. To me it sounds like some wrong command in compilation ie. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748837/c-shared-library-undefined-reference-to-fooclasssayhello