# though placed into the mingw folder, an included library header file is not found

Tags: compiler-errors, include, g++, mingw, static-libraries

i have a user-defined c++ library, let's call it *library*. it has several *header* files in its folder which i have dropped into the **mingw** include directory (***mingw\include***). i have also the achirved ***liblibrary.a*** file dropped into the mingw lib directory (***mingw\lib***).

and in a main.cpp file, i have included one of the header files following the rules e.g like when you include the openGL header files; this is what we do

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

and so my include looks like this

```
#include <library/header.h>
int main (){
   /*
    ** blah blah
    */

}
```

and in compiling,

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

the compiler complains that it can't find the library/header.h file, what could i be doing wrong?

so that i don't get to link it..

```
g++ -llibrary main.o -o main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
g++ main.cpp -llibrary -o main
```

[**ref**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2487723)