# undefined reference to `bfd_get_section_by_name'

Tags: c, binutils

I have this C code:

```
asection *s;
s = bfd_get_section_by_name( abfd, "__exported_do_funs" );
```

Which gives me a compile error:

```
file.o: In function `do_listdos':
file.c:9500: undefined reference to `bfd_get_section_by_name'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I've found this is part of binutils I believe, and installed it:

```
Installed Packages
binutils.i386                     2.17.50.0.6-26.el5        installed
binutils-devel.i386               2.17.50.0.6-26.el5        installed
```

But still get the same compile error. Am I missing something?

I'm running: `gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)`

This is in my header file:

```
#include <bfd.h> /* Eizneckam's BFD Code */
```

The gcc syntax running is:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -c -g -g3 -Wall    -DREQUESTS -DSMAUG14  -DTIMEFORMAT -DREGEX file.c

/usr/bin/gcc    -lcrypt -lz -lbfd -liberty -lm -lmysqlclient -lnsl -L/usr/lib/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/ -o
```

The lib is found in `/usr/lib/libbfd.a`

Comment: You should be including the .h file that defines this function...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @ericbn I understand the concept and I have the setup correctly from what I understand. I'm not sure why the error is happening.

Comment: You need to put the library references after the object files. So move all the `-lbdf` and similar to the end of your compiler line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to link against BFD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915623/unable-to-link-against-bfd)

Answer (score 1):

This means it didn't find the implementation of this function.

In your case:

> To use the library, include `bfd.h` and link with `libbfd.a`.

Reference: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/bfd_3.html

Comment: Is `-lbfd` the correct gcc switch? That's what already exists in the gcc args

Comment: Yeah, that includes the libbfd

Comment: Yep still gets same error. Here's the full compile log: http://biyg.org/maketxt.txt

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix