# How to set library flags after source file in cmake?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm trying to compile a project using hwloc with CMake. However, I get a ton of undefined reference errors when linking:

```
undefined reference to `hwloc_get_type_depth'
undefined reference to `hwloc_bitmap_zero'
[...]
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517138/trying-to-include-a-library-but-keep-getting-undefined-reference-to-messages#2487723) to a similar question the order of flags is important.

So, how can I generate a command like this in CMake? :

`g++ -Wall -std=c++11 source.cpp`**`-lhwloc`**

Excerpt from my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11 -lhwloc")

set(SOURCE_FILES source.cpp)
add_executable(source ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: My question was proposed as a possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file), however the flag I wanted to add was to link against a library and not a normal compile flag as seems to be the case in the above mentioned question. @Edgar Rokyan provided the right answer for my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add linker or compile flag in cmake file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add "-l" (ell) compiler flag in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136418/how-to-add-l-ell-compiler-flag-in-cmake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to link against *hwloc* library you might use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) command:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11") # <== remove *-lhwloc*

set(SOURCE_FILES source.cpp)
add_executable(source ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(source hwloc) # <== add this line
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed it. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible.